# Printing the email and phone of authors just in the footnote with achemso

Tags: footnotes, achemso

I remove the printing of the reference author in the page with `\setkeys{acs}{email=false}` but i would like to have it, with phone number, in the footnote after "To whom correspondence should be addressed", is it possible?

MWE

```
\documentclass[journal=jpccck,manuscript=article,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{email=false}
\author{aut1}
\author{aut2}
\author{aut3}
\affiliation[uni1]{university 1}
\author{aut4}
\affiliation[uni2]{University2}
\author{aut5}
\affiliation{University1}
\email{something@something}
\phone{+03301}
\title[title] {title}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you by providing a minimal working example, which is fully compilable and contains code illustrating you problem starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should know, that you always can modify your question and everything relevant should be given there. So I added your MWE to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found out:

```
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\oldmaketitle
\begin{abstract}
Blablabla\\ 
\end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
{
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}%
{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnotetext[1]{To whom correspondence should be addressed. E-mail: something@something. Tel: 33 (0) 1 . Fax: 33 (0) 1 .}
\footnotetext[2]{Uni1}
\footnotetext[3]{Uni2}
}
```

In this way i can have an abstract in the whole page inside a two column document and i can have the footnotes of the author, specifying the text of every footnote. In fact, adding

```
  \twocolumn[
        \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \oldmaketitle
        \begin{abstract}
        Blablabla\\ 
        \end{abstract}
        \end{@twocolumnfalse}
        ]
```

the automatic footnotes defined in the class don't work anymore but with

```
   {
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}%
    {\fnsymbol{footnote}}
    \footnotetext[1]{}   
}
```

you can add the footnotes again and also specify the text of every footnote.